# os.Pipe not working as expected with log package

Tags: logging, go, stdout, stderr

I have a piece of code which sets up an `os.Pipe` to capture Stdout/Stderr:

https://github.com/sevagh/stdcap/blob/master/stdcap.go

```
// Capture executes f() and returns the captured data
func (s *stdcap) Capture(f func()) string {
    s.mu.Lock()
    defer s.mu.Unlock()

    var old, r, w *os.File

    if s.out {
        old = os.Stdout
        r, w, _ = os.Pipe()
        os.Stdout = w
    } else {
        old = os.Stderr
        r, w, _ = os.Pipe()
        os.Stderr = w
    }

    f()

    outC := make(chan string)
    defer close(outC)

    go func() {
        var buf bytes.Buffer
        io.Copy(&buf, r)
        outC <- buf.String()
    }()

    w.Close()

    if s.out {
        os.Stdout = old
    } else {
        os.Stderr = old
    }

    return <-outC
}
```

Today I tried using this code with the `log` package and it doesn't work.

This works:

```
func TestOutCapture(t *testing.T) {
    sc := StdoutCapture()
    out := sc.Capture(func() {
        fmt.Printf("Hello world!")
    })

    if out != "Hello world!" {
        t.Errorf("Expected \"Hello world!\", got: %s\n", out)
    }
}

func TestErrCapture(t *testing.T) {
    sc := StderrCapture()
    err := sc.Capture(func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Hello world!")
    })

    if err != "Hello world!" {
        t.Errorf("Expected \"Hello world!\", got: %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

These don't work:

```
func TestLogOutCapture(t *testing.T) {
    sc := StdoutCapture()

    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
    out := sc.Capture(func() {
        log.Printf("Hello world!")
    })

    if out != "Hello world!" {
        t.Errorf("Expected \"Hello world!\", got: %s\n", out)
    }
}

func TestLogErrCapture(t *testing.T) {
    sc := StderrCapture()
    log.SetOutput(os.Stderr)

    err := sc.Capture(func() {
        log.Printf("Hello world!")
    })

    if err != "Hello world!" {
        t.Errorf("Expected \"Hello world!\", got: %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

Any ideas on where I can debug this? Does the Golang `log` package not use `os.Stdout/os.Stderr`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logging package [initializes the standard logger with the value `os.Stderr` at initialization time](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go#L73).  Modifications to the variable `os.Stderr` do not change the value in the [logger field](https://golang.org/src/log/log.go#L54).

Call [log.SetOutput](https://godoc.org/log#Logger.SetOutput) to change the output location for the standard logger from your capture function. Unfortunately, there's not a way to get standard logger's output so you can save and restore it in your capture function.

Comment: Thanks. Since the purpose of stdcap is unit testing, it's easy enough to call `log.SetOutput` within my unit test.